¿Cómo instalar Blas en un proyecto de Django?
Tengo un proyecto de Django. Cuando ejecuto el comando pip install -r Requirements.txt, salta un error de Blas:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blas==1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for blas==1.0

He intentado hacer pip install blas y me da un error parecido. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?
